# Disable context menu in GWT RichTextArea

Tags: gwt, contextmenu, rich-text-editor

I'm developing a kind of WYSIWYG editor in GWT. In order to show my own context menu, I have to disable the default browser's menu. I was doing this by simply adding an attribute to the RichTextArea element (oncontextmenu = "return false;"), which in chrome works well, but in FireFox doesn't.

I've been looking for possible solutions in the web for hours but I can't get any to work.

Something that I notice is that, when adding a context menu handler to my RichTextArea, it never gets fired.

If anyone has faced this same problem and could point me in the right direction I would really appreciated it.